# Json Formatted with Square Brackets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, format

I tried to render json where the root directory is enclosed in square brackets. My required format is:

```
[{"status":"Failure","message":"Invalid Credentials"}]
```

My code is:

```
render :json=> [{:status=>'Failure',:message=>'Invalid Credentials'}], :status=>422
```

I can't get the square brackets in the response. My current response is:

```
{"status":"Failure","message":"Invalid Credentials"}
```

How can I obtain the required format?

Comment: obviously you cannot make it as you want. json response is always is in `{}` . you can try differently like `{ :op => [{"status":"Failure","message":"Invalid Credentials"}] }`.

Comment: what is _square_ root ?

Comment: Rails is sending it correct way.. I think problem is on the _response receiving_ side ?

Comment: show your rails server log .........

Comment: @Mani Yes,, any object ( which responds_to `to_json` method) can be rendered using `json: ....object`

Comment: Nop. till the time josn response is there. json standard is defined see this http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ecma-st/ECMA-262.pdf

Comment: When you say "square root" do you mean "square bracket", ie `"["`?

Comment: A square root is a mathematical term -  2 is the square root of 4, 3 is the square root of 9, etc.  That's really confusing....

Comment: haha, yes, you are right:  the square root of 4 can also be `-2`.  So the square root of 4 is `±2`.  Hopefully Mani learned the difference between a square root and a square bracket/brace anyway, despite my error :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you will want to do is name the entire object you wish to receive in return. Square brackets indicate an array, but JSON always returns a HASH (curly braces)... the trick is that this hash may CONTAIN an array. So instead of:

```
render :json=> [{:status=>'Failure',:message=>'Invalid Credentials'}], :status=>422
```

Do this:

```
render :json=> { :my_array => [{:status=>'Failure',:message=>'Invalid Credentials'}], :status=>422 }
```

Then, instead of getting json object (which we'll just call my_json), get my_json[:my_array]. This will return the object you were describing.

Comment: `[]` is a valid JSON document.

Comment: Yes, in the same way that the OP's opening statement is valid JSON, but it returns the content those braces unless I'm wildly incorrect, so what you just said would equate to nil (not `[ nil ]`). I'll have to verify that I'm not going crazy, but I believe everything in my answer remains correct.

Comment: My complaint is that your answer introduces a level of junk which is highly undesirable.

Comment: That is a separate, but distinctly invalid, issue. If the user requires an array of a hash of two values, this is the way to pass that object. The necessity for it to be in the form of an array is the additional level of junk, but given the paradigm of the question we must accommodate that. Further, depending on how the OP intends to use this object it may prove cleaner to fetch his values by a label, rather then operating upon the whole object (especially given the presence of two different "status" keys).

Answer (score 0):

The Rails `json` rendering system leaves a lot to be desired. Here's a work-around:

```
render(
  text: [ {:status=>'Failure',:message=>'Invalid Credentials'} ].to_json,
  content_type: 'application/json',
  status: 422
)
```

You can force whatever you want through the system if you're willing to do the encoding yourself. Rails won't touch the content of a `text` render call, it just sends that through faithfully.

It's worth noting that some modules can alter the behaviour of the `render(json:...)` method, like [jBuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder).

If you do this frequently, you might want to make a method in your controller that encapsulates this properly, like:

```
def render_json(object, options = nil)
  render({
    text: object.to_json,
    content_type: 'application.json'
  }.merge(options || { }))
end
```

It's a little obnoxious to have to do this, but Rails does presume a little too much about how you want to encode your JSON data.